# AS3 Make function listen to different kinds of events

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a login function that activates after the user enters his Username and Password and clicks the Login button. It works perfectly, but some people want to do things faster; instead of clicking the button after entering the password, they want to press Enter to Login... But at the same time, I want the Login button to work too. How do I make a function listen to 2 different kinds of events (a MouseEvent and a KeyboardEvent)?

I've tried things like `checkLogin(e:MouseEvent || e:KeyboardEvent)` But they just threw me errors.

Here's my code...

```
function checkLogin(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Submition Going Down!!");
    if (username.text == "" || password.text == "")
    {
        //Lots and lots of checks...
    else
    {
        //if the user and pass fields are valid
        logErrorT.text = "\n\nRequesting Login...";
        processLogin();
    }
}
loginButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkLogin);
//All this listens for clicks only.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple actually. First, you have to un-limit the kind of event `checkLogin` listens for, like this:

```
function checkLogin(e:Event):void
{
    //code
}
```

Then you just need it to listen for the keyboard event...

```
function runCheck(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (e.charCode == 13) //charCode 13 is Enter
        {
            checkLogin(e);
            //e is the KeyboardEvent.
        }
    }
password.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, runCheck);
```

Hope I helped, I didn't have this problem for too long, but I wasn't able to find an answer for it online either. So I thought I'd give any confused beginners the answer. Good Luck! ^^

Comment: maybe it's better to attach the eventlisterer for the keyboard to the parent of all textfields, now the enter-key-press is only fired when the user has focus on the password field and not when the user has focus on the username textfield. Also I think it's better to listen on the KEY_UP instead of the KEY_DOWN event

Comment: @StefanvandeVooren Actually, it Will only activate when pressed in the password field, seeing as the listener is attached to the password textfield: `password.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, runCheck);` ps: I'd like to learn, what are the advantages of using KEY_UP instead of KEY_DOWN? Thanks ^^

Comment: Sorry, I thought normal HTLM forms with submit forms are submitted on the enter key up, but you were right with the key down. So no advantage for KEY_UP. Because in your question you have "if (username.text == "" || password.text == "")" I assumed you have 2 inputfields. I think it's strange when the enter key is only working when the user has focus on the password input field an not on the username field. T